# Connect to Azure SQL Database from Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I have successfully published Azure App Service from VS-2019 using WebForms. I have successfully secured it so that users must login using an Azure AAD account in the same domain as the App Service. I have successfully created an Azure SQL database. I have successfully added users from the AAD domain to the database and connected to the db, from within the Azure App Service, by hard-coding one of the Azure AAD account users I created, into the connection string.

Now I want to use the authenticated AAD user from the App Service login to connect to the Azure SQL database. Everything I've tried thus far has failed.

I'm pretty new to Azure. Most of my experience is with SQL Server/Visual Studio on an internal corporate domain, with no Cloud services whatsoever.

Anyone have any suggestions?

This is my authentication code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.Owin.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Owin;

using System.Net.Http;

namespace Church
{

    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
        private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        private static string aadInstance = EnsureTrailingSlash(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"]);
        private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
        private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

        string authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                    {
                        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                    {
                        var claims = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims;
                        var groups = from c in claims
                                     where c.Type == "groups"
                                     select c;

                        foreach (var group in groups)
                        {
                            context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, group.Value));
                        }
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }

            }
            );
            // This makes any middleware defined above this line run before the Authorization rule is applied in web.config
            app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
        }


        private static string EnsureTrailingSlash(string value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                value = string.Empty;
            }

            if (!value.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                return value + "/";
            }

            return value;
        }

    }


}
```

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

This task a is bit more complicated.
In order to achieve what you desire, you have to configure the EasyAuth (the app service Authentication / Authorization service) to also get an access token for Azure SQL DB.
You can read more about access tokens with Azure app service authentication [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#refresh-identity-provider-tokens).
Pay attention to the part for the `Azure Active Directory` configuration. You will be instructed to go to `https://resources.azure.com/`, find your app service and update the following properties:

> "additionalLoginParams": ["response_type=code id_token",
>   "resource="]

for the resource parameter, you should use `https://database.windows.net/`, which is the identifier of Azure SQL DB. This will allow the app service authentication services (EasyAuth) to get an access token, on behalf of the user for Azure SQL DB. You will then be able to get this access token from the HTTP HEADER `X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ACCESS-TOKEN` (also described on the [same documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#retrieve-tokens-in-app-code)).

Once you manage to get an access token for Azure SQL DB, then you should use token authentication for azure SQL DB and not user/password based. The `token authentication` part of the documentation is [well hidden here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#azure-ad-token) and this example demonstrates it:

```
string ConnectionString =@"Data Source=n9lxnyuzhv.database.windows.net; Initial Catalog=testdb;"
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
conn.AccessToken = "Your JWT token that you took from HTTP HEADER X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ACESS-TOKEN"
conn.Open();
```

Comment: I'm guessing that I need to modify my authentication code to generate a token, before trying to retrieve it.